# Populate ListView with remote images

Tags: android, listview

I am new to Android development and I have this Android activity class which is a ListView with a simple adapter inside. The activity displays a list of product with a title and an image.

I managed to get the title of each item and display them but how can I display my images without any additional class (I don't want to use custom adapter class).

This is my activity class:

```
public class BookletsActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get JSON
    private static String url = "url.json";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "shop_name";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS_STRING = "shop_address";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "shop_url";
    private static final String TAG_BOOKLET_URL = "feuilletez";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    TextView shop_address;
    TextView shop_name;
    TextView shop_url;
    ImageButton feuilletez;
    private ListView list;

    private ImageButton button1;
    private ImageButton button2;
    private ImageButton button3;
    private ImageButton button4;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Portrait only
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Remove title bar
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
                this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booklet_list);


        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetJson().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BookletsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mise à jour...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            JSONArray array = null;
            try {
                array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ArrayList<String> mythumbs = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> myurls = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id --->" + id);
                 String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                 System.out.println("url --->" + url);
                 String created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                 System.out.println("created_at --->" + created_at);
                 String updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
                 System.out.println("updated_at --->" + updated_at);
                 String title = jsonObject.getString("title");  
                 System.out.println("title --->" + title);
                 String thumbnail_url = jsonObject.getString("thumbnail_url");
                 System.out.println("thumbnail_url --->" + thumbnail_url);
                 mythumbs.add(thumbnail_url);
                 String document_url = jsonObject.getString("document_url");
                 System.out.println("document_url --->" + document_url);
                 myurls.add(document_url);
                 String presented = jsonObject.getString("presented");
                 System.out.println("presented --->" + presented);

                System.out.println("mythumbs --->" + mythumbs);
                System.out.println("myurls --->" + myurls);

                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 if(title == "null"){
                     map.put(TAG_NAME, "Notre catalogue");
                }
                else {
                 map.put(TAG_NAME, title);
                }
                 map.put(TAG_ADDRESS_STRING, thumbnail_url  );
                 map.put(TAG_URL, url);
                 map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                 map.put(TAG_BOOKLET_URL, document_url);
                 oslist.add(map);
                        }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            return null;
    }

        private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
          ImageView bmImage;

          public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
              this.bmImage = bmImage;
          }

          protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
              String urldisplay = urls[0];
              Bitmap myImage = null;
              try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              myImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myImage, 300, 200, false);;
              return myImage;


          }

          protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
              bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
          }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(BookletsActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.listvie_booklet_row, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                                TAG_ADDRESS_STRING, TAG_BOOKLET_URL, TAG_ID }, new int[] { R.id.name_shop,
                                R.id.address_shop});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(BookletsActivity.this, PdfReader.class);
                    //  Toast.makeText(ShopsActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("shop_url"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        intent.putExtra("pdfurl",oslist.get(+position).get("feuilletez"));
                        intent.putExtra("pdfname",oslist.get(+position).get("id"));
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animationin, R.anim.animationout);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();



        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ArrayAdapter` to show only titles in rows, but if you want to create custom row then u must to create you custom Adapter.

[From android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) :

> ArrayAdapter Use this adapter when your data source is an array. By
>   default, ArrayAdapter creates a view for each array item by calling
>   toString() on each item and placing the contents in a TextView.
>
> To customize the appearance of each item you can override the
>   toString() method for the objects in your array. Or, to create a view
>   for each item that's something other than a TextView (for example, if
>   you want an ImageView for each array item), extend the ArrayAdapter
>   class and override getView() to return the type of view you want for
>   each item.